# Chaining bash or dash commands with just a space instead of ; semicolon ; or && or &&

Tags: bash, variables, command, chaining, subshell

Normal command chaining methods work normally, for instance:

```
$ (SCRATCH='heya'; echo $SCRATCH)
heya
```

Or using the logic operator && yields predictable results:

```
$ (SCRATCH='heya' && echo $SCRATCH)
heya
```

But if we chain the commands by using a space then things get weird:

```
$ (SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH)
<<just a blank line prints here>>
```

Despite the above, the variable actually WAS set, and I can prove it with this line:

```
$ (DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u $USER)/bus" grdctl status)
RDP:
        Status: enabled
        TLS certificate: /home/guest/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.crt
        TLS key: /home/guest/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.key
        View-only: no
        Username: (hidden)
        Password: (hidden)
```

The above has NO SEMICOLON separating the two commands, and weirdly enough it actually somehow reads the variable and works.

More weirdly, I can break it by inserting the normal requisite
semicolon ; which really ought to be there, like this:

```
$ (DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u $USER)/bus"; grdctl status)
Failed to lookup legacy VNC password schema: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Failed to lookup RDP credentials: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Next, leaving the offending semicolon in place...
I can bring it back to life by exporting the variable,
which makes me think that the grdctl command punts itself into a subshell:

```
$ (export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u $USER)/bus"; grdctl status)
RDP:
        Status: enabled
        TLS certificate: /home/guest/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.crt
        TLS key: /home/guest/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.key
        View-only: no
        Username: (hidden)
        Password: (hidden)
```

And yet, if we directly run the following space separated commands directly, then the variable disappears into the ether without a trace, not even any errors!

```
$ SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH
<<just a blank line prints here>>
```

And if I export the variable, then it gets worse and doesn't even print a blank line!

```
$ export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH
<<nothing shows here, not even a blank line now>>

#And again for good measure, same result:
$ export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH
<<still nothing, same as before>>

#But yeah, the variable did export to my shell because:
$ echo $SCRATCH
heya
```

So not only does the semicolon send make the variable unreachable by echo, but it also prevents echo from seeing the parent environment!

And it's not just the built-in echo command that's hosed, printf is sick too:

```
$ EPHEMERAL='blink' printf "$EPHEMERAL\n"
<<again, a suffocated blank line here>>
```

But the grdctl command, which is a binary file (neither a script nor a built-in) is perfectly happy to ingest my variable sans semicolon, and output correctly:

```
$ unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
$ DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u $USER)/bus" grdctl status
RDP:
        Status: enabled
        TLS certificate: /home/guest/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.crt
        TLS key: /home/guest/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.key
        View-only: no
        Username: (hidden)
        Password: (hidden)
```

The above seems extremely inconsistent behavior, in that the echo command behaves one way, while the grdctl behaves another way.

I've googled incessantly and consulted with AI's but nobody can explain the chaining of commands with spaces, which is definitely "a thing" because it often works.

There are tens of thousands of explanations on the Internet about how ; or && or || can be used to chain commands, but not a peep about the space character.

-------------- MY FINAL UPDATE --------------

Okay based on all the good discussions below, here is workaround #1:

```
$ YUCK=pid; YUCK=stu sh -c 'echo -n $YUCK';echo $YUCK
```

And here is workaround #2:

```
$ echo 'printf $SOMEVAR"\n"' > myscript.sh; chmod u+x myscript.sh
$ SOMEVAR='blink' ./myscript.sh
```

Clearly some commands require workarounds while others don't.

Comment: `echo` isn't an external executable and also doesn't read variable values from its environment. It is a builtin. You're not chaining with a space - you're trying to set a variable's value in the environment of an executable.

Comment: Interesting observation, nevertheless I'm thinking that the parsing sequence used to render the content of $SCRATCH would be the same in any case ...or is it? I'm more than happy to always use the semicolons and add "export" as necessary, but I've seen the "space" joiner used in several scripts and so it would be great to have this documented in some easy to understand way.

Comment: `foo=12 some_program` sets the value of `foo` to 12 in the environment of `some_program`. `export foo=12` does the same thing except that the variable and its value are available in any subsequent executable's environment. `echo` is a builtin. It doesn't get spawned so it doesn't get a new environment. It also doesn't read variables from the environment.

Comment: I just did some more testing and found that printf has the same issue as echo, yet printf is not a built-in: $ whereis printf ... /usr/bin/printf, so something else is lurking in the shadows.

Comment: Just because there's a command named `printf` on your system doesn't mean there isn't also a builtin named `printf` which your code is using instead of the external command. Try `type -a printf` instead of `whereis printf` and then `printf --version` (calls the version of `printf` you're actually using which is probably the builtin) vs `/usr/bin/printf --version` (calls the version of the external command `printf` you probably are not using).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Using *buitin* or not doesn't matter! Try to replace `echo` by `/bin/echo`!  The question  is: *where are the variable expanded* (at which level)?

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: None of the builtins read variable values from temporary assignments through the environment. The external `/bin/echo` doesn't either. It's not a question of where a variable is expanded, it's one of where (which environment or other means) a command or executable retrieves values from. `echo` and `/bin/echo` only accept arguments on their command lines. They know nothing at all about variables which they never see. The shell has already expanded them to values beforehand. They also don't read from stdin.

Comment: That's the million dollar question, and yes, it's definitely something to do with how the shell processes expansions, because the following line replies with `outer` whereas `inner` is actually expected:
EPHEMERAL=outer; EPHEMERAL=inner /bin/printf $EPHEMERAL'\n'
Now, type -a does show printf as a builtin but I've googled and AI'ed for at over 2 hours and no official explanation comes forth about how built-ins are processed differently.

Comment: HMM: $ type -a printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
printf is /bin/printf
BUT: $ type -a /bin/printf
/bin/printf is /bin/printf
SO: what will it be... Built-in or not? Can we have it both ways?

Comment: `inner` is certainly **not** expected. `$EPHEMERAL` is expanded before `printf` runs. Try `EPHEMERAL=outer; EPHEMERAL=inner bash -c 'echo $EPHEMERAL'` and contrast with `EPHEMERAL=outer; EPHEMERAL=inner bash -c "echo $EPHEMERAL"`

Comment: read [how commands are parsed in a posix shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01); bash is [similar](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Executing-Commands)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson When you hit: `TZ=Asia/Pyongyang printf '%(%T)T\n' -1`, you use ***builtin***, with ***temporary variable***! Again **builtin** or not **builtin** does not matter!

Comment: @jhnc. Hey, your posix and bash reference docs link above is an absolute godsend. Thanks for posting it. Others take notice!

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that bash is allowing an exported temporary env var to be defined "on the fly" before a command to be executed.

```
SOME_VAR_TO_BE_EXPORTED="value only for the command" some_command
```

Example:

```
echo 'printf "MY_ENV_VAR=%s" $MY_ENV_VAR\n' > myscript.sh
chmod a+x ./myscript.sh
```

Now let's execute it with a **prefixed** env var definition

```
# just to be sure
unset MY_ENV_VAR
MY_ENV_VAR=value ./myscript.sh
```

will output:

```
MY_ENV_VAR=value
```

but `$MY_ENV_VAR` scope only exists during the call (assuming it wasn't set before)

```
echo $MY_ENV_VAR
```

should be empty

Some explanations here:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/set-env-variables-bash-command

Official documentation here

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html

The paragraph:

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.

So yes it's a confusing syntax. The missing semi-colon is on purpose here for this specific syntax, that just work for envvar assignment.

A semi-colon would produce a distinct behavior: 2 instructions. So defining the variable, not necessary also exporting it, then executing the command (eventually expanding the variable before the second instruction is executed)

---

What about `EPHEMERAL='blink' printf "$EPHEMERAL\n"` ...prints nothing?

Well, temporary envvar export could be explained as the following pseudo-code:

```
old_EPHEMERAL=$EPHEMERAL
export EPHEMERAL='blink'
# assuming `printf` is any command or function to call here 
printf "$old_EPHEMERAL\n"
if [[ -n $old_EPHEMERAL ]]
then
  EPHEMERAL=$old_EPHEMERAL
fi
# the old value, was only mentioned for the pseudo-code
unset old_EPHEMERAL
```

but all-in-one!

that mean the `export EPHEMERAL='blink'` is not yet available when the **all-in-one** is evaluated.

So when the `printf "$EPHEMERAL\n"` is evaluated (not called yet) value is whatever it would **before** the export will happen. Then, the command is called with the argument and also the envvar becomes available as `$EPHEMERAL` (with value `blink` during the call)

---

One was missing and I was curious about it, and I finally got it:

What about `export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH` prints nothing even if `$SCRATCH` has an old value.

`export` is a built-in **command**, that takes as argument some variable(s) name and change their export status. It can take multiple argument with and without assignment. It outputs nothing and mostly always returns `$?` 0 (success) even on assignment with errors `v=$(false)`. It only returns failure status on rare use-case where the assignment is failing: like invalid variable name, system failure like out of memory, or readonly variable assignment, etc. See: [SC2155](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2155)

So `export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH` is decomposing in the following pseudo-code, still all-in-one. ⚠️ Note: that this is **not** recognized as an *augmented-temporarily-by-prefixing-it-with-parameter* as it's evaluated as a *command*.

```bash
# pseudo code decomposition:
# export and assign $SCRATCH
export SCRATCH='heya'
# export a variable named $echo
export echo
# export a variable from the expansion of the old value of $SCRATCH
export $SCRATCH
```

tricky enough?

You can watch the result with this extra command:

```bash
export -p | grep -E 'echo|SCRATCH|heya'
# outputs
declare -x SCRATCH="heya"
declare -x echo
```

What will it output if you run `export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH` twice? (left as an exercise for the reader)

tested with bash version 5.1.16 (See also bash link above ⬆️ for official manual section: *3.7.4 Environment*)

---

Hope that helps, keep reading the doc,  and may be look at [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), you would probably learn many more trick.

Want to become a command line warrior? may this site is still contributed

https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse/sort-by-votes

Comment: While your example does provide a second demonstration of how setting a variable directly on a script (without semicolon) does actually work. No substantiated explanations have been offered yet, for why the same shtick does not work for echo or for printf. $ EPHEMERAL='blink' printf "$EPHEMERAL\n" ...prints nothing, and it does so in contrast to your demo as well as my grdctl command example, near the end of my original post. There is something important and subtle to be learned here. Thanks by the way, for clarifying that this is actually all about variable assignment.

Comment: @snovotill you're right, This is a bit subtle here too. So let's EDIT to post...

Comment: Interesting I got -1 vote here.

Comment: I've up-voted this because it does make printf work as expected (... echo 'echo $MY_ENV_VAR' > myscript.sh ...also) when invoked within a script, but someone ought to explain why external commands work while built-ins don't (if that's actually the whole story, which it might not be).

Comment: @snovotill from my test and experience: builtin vs non-builtin has nothing related here. This his all about "scope"  vs "augmented-temporarily-by-prefixing-it-with-parameter" and also how command in bash are "evaluated". Did you catch it or is it still confuse? Do you understand now why "SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH" prints noting nor "export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH" prints any thing? This is not for the same reason. Replacing "echo" by "./myecho.sh" "echo 'echo $1' > ./myecho.sh" wont change that behavior. 

Comment: @john-kugelman I didn't know that someone can edit other's answer. Interesting. 

Comment: All I know is that stuffing it into a script or a sub-shell changes the parsing order and makes it work. $ YUCK=pid; YUCK=stu sh -c 'echo -n $YUCK';echo $YUCK ...so some commands work as expected, others need work-around and you can put the fork in me ...I'm done!

Comment:  @snovotill bash is an ancient program that traversed the computer age with layer on top of others. So the behavior (strange behavior) comes from that onion layer and more or less retro compatibly stuff. Understanding it takes a lot of time and to fall into pitfall. Keep trying and asking, there seems to have a lot of passionate scripter around here. 

Comment: I'm starting to equate bash with X11, which is also quite the patchwork! Another good comparison is the Chinese language which is grammatically simple but very very highly evolved ...quirky. In the end though, bash is not nearly as complicated and intricate as javascript with all its millions of features and extensions. I can fathom burning 3 full months out of my life on bash ;o)

Comment: @snovotill fair enough! I finally added the last explanation for `export SCRATCH='heya' echo $SCRATCH` prints nothing